# Can not create shared-domain in Cloud Foundry - 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: vmware, openstack, cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I can not create shared-domain in Cloud Foundry, any pushed apps get's health check connection refused.

I had working Cloud Foundry environment based on OpenStack IaaS. Everything worked as expected. I took my deployment files and after some time deployed it successfully in IaaS Vmware VSphere 7. The problem is, that every app that I push has problems with health check:

```
   2020-10-29T16:55:01.43+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 938b869c-5a68-40cc-9486-c5bc0d53a73a successfully destroyed container for instance 44e9c2a6-b54d-4fc4-4118-6d6d
   2020-10-29T16:55:36.55+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 938b869c-5a68-40cc-9486-c5bc0d53a73a creating container for instance 17f161a2-9788-426d-414d-6c33
   2020-10-29T16:55:37.18+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 938b869c-5a68-40cc-9486-c5bc0d53a73a successfully created container for instance 17f161a2-9788-426d-414d-6c33
   2020-10-29T16:55:37.47+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Downloading droplet...
   2020-10-29T16:55:37.75+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Downloaded droplet
   2020-10-29T16:55:37.75+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2020-10-29T16:56:38.45+0000 [HEALTH/0] ERR Failed to make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused
   2020-10-29T16:56:38.45+0000 [CELL/0] ERR Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.
   2020-10-29T16:56:38.46+0000 [CELL/SSHD/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2020-10-29T16:56:38.48+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 143
```

I am also not able to create any shared domains:

```
bash-5.0# cf create-shared-domain tcp.cf.test-env.net --router-group default-tcp -v
REQUEST: [2020-10-29T17:03:33Z]
GET /v2/info HTTP/1.1
Host: api.cf.test-env.net
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: cf/6.47.2+d526c2cb3.2019-11-05 (go1.12.12; amd64 linux)

RESPONSE: [2020-10-29T17:03:33Z]
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 561
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2020 17:03:33 GMT
Server: nginx
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Vcap-Request-Id: 4badb79b-2faf-4623-6c3c-ce5fa3223cd5::dc43d2c9-c902-4429-9d65-d9a0060983c5
{
  "api_version": "2.144.0",
  "app_ssh_endpoint": "ssh.cf.test-env.net:2222",
  "app_ssh_host_key_fingerprint": "ae:a3:ed:ad:37:d3:8a:7b:ed:b4:e5:d2:25:e5:8c:d0",
  "app_ssh_oauth_client": "ssh-proxy",
  "authorization_endpoint": "https://login.cf.test-env.net",
  "build": "",
  "description": "",
  "doppler_logging_endpoint": "wss://doppler.cf.test-env.net:443",
  "min_cli_version": null,
  "min_recommended_cli_version": null,
  "name": "",
  "osbapi_version": "2.15",
  "routing_endpoint": "https://api.cf.test-env.net/routing",
  "support": "",
  "token_endpoint": "https://uaa.cf.test-env.net",
  "version": 0
}


REQUEST: [2020-10-29T17:03:33Z]
GET /login HTTP/1.1
Host: login.cf.test-env.net
Accept: application/json
Connection: close
User-Agent: cf/6.47.2+d526c2cb3.2019-11-05 (go1.12.12; amd64 linux)

RESPONSE: [2020-10-29T17:03:34Z]
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 384
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2020 17:03:34 GMT
Set-Cookie: X-Uaa-Csrf=NJlSPAjspn7m8oWuQdKsVD; Max-Age=86400; Expires=Fri, 30-Oct-2020 17:03:34 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Vcap-Request-Id: 577d4d31-ec30-477e-6f44-c0dd9306270d
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
{
  "app": {
    "version": "74.12.0"
  },
  "commit_id": "7311e68",
  "entityID": "login.cf.test-env.net",
  "idpDefinitions": {},
  "links": {
    "login": "https://login.cf.test-env.net",
    "passwd": "/forgot_password",
    "register": "/create_account",
    "uaa": "https://uaa.cf.test-env.net"
  },
  "prompts": {
    "password": "[PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]",
    "username": [
      "text",
      "Email"
    ]
  },
  "timestamp": "2019-12-02T22:53:03+0000",
  "zone_name": "uaa"
}


Creating shared domain tcp.cf.test-env.net as admin...
REQUEST: [2020-10-29T17:03:34Z]
GET /routing/v1/router_groups?name=default-tcp HTTP/1.1
Host: api.cf.test-env.net
Accept: application/json
Authorization: [PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: cf/6.47.2+d526c2cb3.2019-11-05 (go1.12.12; amd64 linux)
[application/json Content Hidden]

RESPONSE: [2020-10-29T17:03:34Z]
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 114
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2020 17:03:34 GMT
X-Vcap-Request-Id: 9459b068-0987-4f5e-7dee-1efdb5ca6fb8
[
  {
    "guid": "343ba1e8-88a7-4003-6db6-4feabedd072b",
    "name": "default-tcp",
    "reservable_ports": "1024-2048",
    "type": "tcp"
  }
]


REQUEST: [2020-10-29T17:03:34Z]
POST /v2/shared_domains HTTP/1.1
Host: api.cf.test-env.net
Accept: application/json
Authorization: [PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: cf/6.47.2+d526c2cb3.2019-11-05 (go1.12.12; amd64 linux)
{
  "internal": false,
  "name": "tcp.cf.test-env.net",
  "router_group_guid": "343ba1e8-88a7-4003-6db6-4feabedd072b"
}


RESPONSE: [2020-10-29T17:04:04Z]
HTTP/1.0 504 Gateway Time-out
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
<html><body><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1>
The server didn't respond in time.
</body></html>


Error unmarshalling the following into a cloud controller error: <html><body><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1>
The server didn't respond in time.
</body></html>

FAILED
```

I suspect network configuration issue, that blocks some internal CF parts from connection. There is no any firewall or any rules found in VMware. I can also ping and make ssh connection between bosh created VM's.

Any ideas, what else can I do?

Comment: Look at the ingress path for network traffic to your system domain. Check that DNS is set up correctly & that your load balancer is working correctly & able to talk to your Gorouters. The 504 isn't coming from gorouter cause the format would look different, so it's probably coming from something upstream, like your LB. A quick/easy check is to look at the Gorouter access log and see if the failing requests are ever getting there. If you don't see them in that log, then they don't make it.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I was checking with tcpdump how the traffic looks like on gorouters and found why it is not working well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with DNAT and SNAT rules on VmWare NSX-T. If any internal VM asked about dns name "api.cf.test-env.net" it get's remote (public) IP address as answer. When the connection should be established, the internal VM has been asking api.cf.test-env.net by public IP address, and get's the local one by second stage of TCP three-way-handshake - what caused TCP RST. After creating DNAT and SNAT rules correctly, everything works as expected. I still wondering why "api.cf.test-env.net" is not answered by bosh-dns with internal address. Does anyone know why it so and how it can be changed?